# How to do a secondary sort on filenames with numbers in hadoop streaming?

Tags: sorting, hadoop, hadoop-streaming, hadoop-partitioning, secondary-sort

I'm trying to sort file names such as

```
    cat1.pdf, cat2.pdf, ... cat10.pdf ...
```

I'm utilizing a sort right now with the following parameters:

```
    -D mapreduce.job.output.key.comparator.class=org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.partition.KeyFieldBasedComparator 
    -D stream.num.map.output.key.fields=2 
    -D mapreduce.partition.keypartitioner.options="-k1,1" 
    -D mapreduce.partition.keycomparator.options="-k1,1 -k2,2 -V" 
    -partitioner org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.KeyFieldBasedPartitioner
```

The key value pairs are separated by a tab with the file name as the value and a string as the key. The problem is that my sort right now secondary sorts the file names such that I get

```
    cat1.pdf, cat10.pdf, cat2.pdf, cat3.pdf, cat30.pdf ...
```

How can I get it such that the files are sorted like this:

```
    cat1.pdf, cat2.pdf, cat3.pdf ... cat10.pdf,cat11.pdf...
```

I'm using hadoop streaming 2.7.1

Comment: try this one http://riccomini.name/posts/hadoop/2009-11-13-sort-reducer-input-value-hadoop/

Comment: That isn't for hadoop streaming though